# How to push an array into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
data = [];
data.push({arrayName:x,secondArray: {name:x, value:y}});
```

Now how can you push an item into secondArray ?
have tried with

```
data[0].secondArray.push({name:x, value:y});
```

But getting error like  `data[0].secondArray.push()` is not a function.

Comment: secondArray is an object and not an array

Comment: `{arrayName:x,secondArray: {name:x, value:y}}` is object not `array`..Try `data[0].secondArray={name:x, value:y};` or if you want `secondArray` to be an array then initialize it as an `array`. `ata[0].secondArray.push({name:x, value:y});` will work in that case..

Answer (score 2):

This is because `secondArray` is not a `array` but an `object`.

To add properties in an object you can use

```
secondArray.propertyName = Value;//not to use this syntax if 'propertyName' if not a valid string.

secondArray[propertyName] = Value;
```

For eg use : `data[0].secondArray.name = 'x';`

Comment: @RayonDabre Actually, it *does* answer the question as much as possible.

Comment: @ammoQ, if _This is because secondArray is not a array but an object_ does answer this question according to you then **no more arguments** I feel question is unclear hence it is better to understand the question to provide better solution..

Comment: @RayonDabre The first revision of the answer didn't answer the question, you are right. When I came in, there already was the second revision with some code that IMO answers the question as good as possible.

Comment: The time I posted my first revision, your comment was already there @RayonDabre. I appologize for the inappropiate answer the very first time!!

Comment: I am so quick you know :P Never mind bro :) **Happy Coding**